# How do you handle the back button in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, pushstate

I just can't find a satisfying way to handle the Browser's History. Sure there are lovely plugins like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), which works fine for smaller things. But let me give you an example:

I have a multi-paged form that asks the user for different things. After every submit to the next page (actually the same, it just changes the view depending on HTTP-POST variables), there are some animations and changes on the page:

- the main content changes to the next form (with a slideUp/slideDown)
- the progress bar changes it's state with an animation
- below this bar, some information about **some** of the input fades in

So that's pretty basic right now, but I'm already struggling, because all the animations (the last 2 parts) are different on every state (different div, different input-sources) and I have no idea how to make them so generic, that I have not to specify them separatly.

I could live with that though, but when a user hits the back button I have to redefine all those animations again (in reverse). The content-load sure is no problem, it basically just reloads the file with an ajax-load:

- I execute a `pushstate` with the input data as the `stateObj` on submit
- so I can execute the content-load in the bound 'statechange' event

As said though, the rest drives me insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of punching around and stuff, I decided to degrade to the simplest and best solution for my problem: Using the basics.

Instead of animating everything backwards/forwards when the user hits the back/forward buttons, I just reloaded the whole site with ajax so I can use the HTML/PHP fallback with the stateObj of the selected site.

Problem with History.js though is that it can't distinguish between pushState and back/forward button in the onstatechange-event. So I degraded from History.js to the standard W3C behaviour with pushstate. There will be an update with 1.8.0 that allows to distinguish between internal and external statechanges.

Thanks for all the answers, but I guess this is the most accurate way of dealing with it, while using MVC alone doesn't solve the problem - why I didn't accept any other answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend grabbing and learning Backbone.js. It plays great with jQuery and sets up your website in a modified MVC pattern. It also has a great system for handling URL changes and executing the appropriate code.

As for sliding, if you want to reverse animations, that could be a bit of a pain to keep track of. What I did with my app when I was sliding between screens is instead of sometimes sliding up and sometimes sliding down, I would always move the element in the DOM that I was sliding to so that it was after the element I was sliding from. That way the slide was always going in the same direction and my animations wouldn't get all goofy.

Comment: I'll have a look into backbone.js, thanks. Do you also have an example how exactly it would help me in my situation ? The sliding is no problem for me, as I'm either detecting the wanted elements position automatically or I just always slide-in and out from/to the same direction

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), which includes jQuery. Not sure if it meets your exact requirements but it is JavaScript and MVC...

Comment: Could you give me some examples how exactly it would help me in my situation ? I'm actually not a big fan of frameworks as I like to have everything as slim as possible, no extra-weight. My projects aren't that huge and I'm the only developer, my php mvc is handmade too.

Comment: At the moment, no, I only have very limited internet access and my dev rig is boxed up...But, I have a back-end developer colleague that has a limited understanding of JavaScript and recently used JMVC in a personal project and swears by it - really easy to use and hook up with the back-end, and it's modular so you only use the bits you actually need and don't have to use the entire framework every time. Personally I prefer frameworks as they have already been thoroughly bug tested by the community, and tend to be written to very high code standards :)

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite strictly MVC (of which there are several for JavaScript) I think [backbone js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) is a great framework, that is based around the concepts of MVC, but re-worked to better suit the JavaScript language and environment.

Comment: Same here, can you give me some examples for my specific problem here ? I didn't just ask for any MVC or similar but some solution for problems like mine...and how those solutions look like. Just a framework is not enough

Comment: It is beyond the scope of this answer to give you a background of how the backbone.js framework works.